# Listeners conflict while working with dnd-kit

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, dnd-kit

I am working on a todo list application and I wanted to make the todos draggable.
I am using dnd-kit to achieve the same.

I provided the DndContext and SortableContext in my parent container.
ListContainer.jsx

```
          <DndContext collisionDetection={closestCorners}>
            <SortableContext
              items={toDo}
              strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
            >
              <div className="bg-red-900">
                {toDo.map((item) => (
                  <ToDo
                    key={item._id}
                    id={item._id}
                    value={text}
                    isCompleted={item.completed}
                    text={item.text}
                    updateTodo={() => updateTodo(item._id, item.text)}
                    deleteTodo={() => deleteToDo(user.id, item._id, setToDo)}
                    updateState={() => updateState(item._id)}
                    inputRef={inputRef}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            </SortableContext>
          </DndContext>
```

And then I used the useSortable hook to destructure some properties necessary to make the todo items draggable.

Todo.jsx

```
  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      {...listeners}
      {...attributes}
      style={style}
      className={`${
        isDark
          ? "bg-black/20 text-white hover:bg-black/60"
          : "bg-gray-50/80 hover:bg-gray-200"
      } w-full md:w-[70%] mx-auto my-2 flex items-center font-[600] font-mono text-lg justify-between rounded-md shadow-md  transition-colors`}
    >
      <div
        className="flex flex-grow items-center h-full p-4 gap-3 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={handleCheckboxChange}
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          className="cursor-pointer"
          readOnly
        />
        <div className={`${isChecked ? "line-through" : ""} select-none`}>
          <p> {text} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-4 px-4 select-none text-lg">
        <button onClick={handleUpdateToDo}>
          <BiEdit />
        </button>
        <button onClick={deleteToDoHandler}>
          <RiDeleteBin6Line />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Having multiple listeners on my todo component was leading to listners conflicts.

I tried to use drag handlers instead but my todos still wont move.

```
  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={style}
      className={`${
        isDark
          ? "bg-black/20 text-white hover:bg-black/60"
          : "bg-gray-50/80 hover:bg-gray-200"
      } w-full md:w-[70%] mx-auto my-2 flex items-center font-[600] font-mono text-lg justify-between rounded-md shadow-md  transition-colors`}
    >
      <div
        className="flex flex-grow items-center h-full p-4 gap-3 cursor-pointer"
        onClick={handleCheckboxChange}
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          className="cursor-pointer"
          readOnly
        />
        <div className={`${isChecked ? "line-through" : ""} select-none`}>
          <p> {text} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-4 px-4 select-none text-lg">
        <button onClick={handleUpdateToDo}>
          <BiEdit />
        </button>
        <button onClick={deleteToDoHandler}>
          <RiDeleteBin6Line />
        </button>
        <button className="px-2 py-2" {...attributes} {...listeners}>
          Drag me
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you provide recording or sandbox it would be easier to understand the problem